# Extracting a string between two patterns in bash with a regex

Tags: regex, string, bash, awk, sed

I have a string with key/value pairs in a bash variable. The value I want is hidden like this.

```
{"keyIDontCareAbout"=>"valueIDontCareAbout",
  "keyForValueIWant"=>"valueIWant",
 ...............bunch more keys 
}
```

What should I use to extract that value? `sed`, `awk`, `expr` match?

My thinking is this, I should extract the string that is preceded by "keyForValueIWant"=>" and is followed by " but I'm having a hard time deciding which tool to use.

`expr` match seems bad, because it grabs a string at the end of an expression or at the beginning of one, but my string is in the middle of a bunch of characters.

Basically, I can't figure out the regex syntax for a substring between two other substrings.

Comment: Post a more complete example with specific input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `awk` as follows:

```
# Specify key of interest.
key='keyForValueIWant' 

# Extract matching value, assuming that the input data is
# in shell variable $input:
value=$(awk -F'("|=>)' -v key="$key" '$2==key { print $5; exit }' <<<"$input")

# Print result.
echo "Value for $key: [$value]"
```

- `-F'("|=>)'` tells `awk` to split each line into fields based on `"` or `=>` as separators - effectively, this will put the the key in field 2 (`$2`), and the value in field 5 (`$5`)
- The key of interest is passed as a shell variable (`$key`) to `awk` as a variable of the same name (`-v key=...`).
- If the input line's key matches the specified key (`$2==key`), the 5th field - containing the value - is printed (`print $5`).
- `exit` ensures that processing stops once a match is found to prevent unnecessary parsing of the remainder of the file (note: this assumes that the keys are true keys, i.e., that they are unique in the input file).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following sed command:

```
valueOfInterest=$(sed -n '/keyForValueIWant/ s/.*=>"\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' <<< "$input")
```

`-n` disables output by default. The regex `/keyForValueIWant/` restricts the following action only to the/those lines which match the regex. The following substitute command filters the value out of the line and prints it `/p`.

Comment: Sorry I should've explained better. What if I want the result in a variable instead of a file?

Comment: Ok. Have edited my answer. Use [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) if you need the output of a command in a variable.

Comment: Can I take off the file.txt?

Comment: Of course. It was just an example. Replace it with your actual input file name.

Comment: My data is not in an input file, it's in a bash variable.

Comment: Ok, got it. And you need the result in a variable or printed to screen?

Comment: Promising, but the lack of _anchoring_ of the regex could yield false positives; also, for optimization it would be better to stop processing input once a match is found.

Comment: I need the result in a variable